localization is not working in multipage classbased application in python
I am using gettext to provide localization in python.I have generated the localization files ,but the localization is not working in multipage application like defining class at one file and and creating object at another file.It worked when i define and create object at same page but when i define class at one page and create object at another page,it does not work.
working code:
# files/y.py

from .localization import setup_translation

# Set the translation here
_ = setup_translation("es")


class Demo:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Demo")
        self.root.geometry("500x400")
        print(_("Hello, World!"))
        print(_("Dashboard"))


import tkinter as tk


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo(root)
    root.mainloop()

not working code:
import tkinter as tk
from files.y import Demo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo(root)
    root.mainloop()


I got the answer,simply have to provide full path of localedir:
def setup_translation(language_code):
    global _
    locales_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "locales")
    print(locales_dir)
    lang = gettext.translation(
        "messages", localedir=locales_dir, languages=[language_code], fallback=True
    )
    lang.install()
    _ = lang.gettext
    return _

